# Real time database in Hadoop ecosystem

Tags: hadoop, hbase, thrift, cloudera-manager

Pardon me if this is a silly question.

I have a cloudera manager installed in a single node.

I am trying to use Hbase and Hadoop for logging request and response in my web application.

I am trying to list latest user activity using the log.

Rows are added using the below table structure.

1 Column Family, RowId, 11 columns. I store every value as string. Fairly simple & similar to a mysql table.

```
RowId
entry:addedTime
entry:value
entry:ip
entry:accessToken
entry:identifier
entry:userId
entry:productId
entry:object
entry:requestHeader
entry:completeDate
entry:tag
```

Now, in order to get rows from my Hbase, I use

```
SingleColumnValueFilter("entry", "userId", "=", binary:"25", true, true)
```

Now, I am struggling to order this by

`entry:completeDate DESCENDING`

and limit by 25 rows for pagination or infinite scroll.

My question,

Is Hbase the only real time querying database available in Hadoop ecosystem?

Am I using Hbase for wrong reasons? Is my table structure correct?

I work in a startup and these are our baby steps to moving to BigData. Though BigData created lot of hype, the Hadoop is poorly supported for latest linux and looks too complicated.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Many thanks,

Karthik

Comment: wouldn't using sql be faster?

Comment: Is it phoenix or Imphal? Which SQL you are referring to?

Comment: how about integrating hive with sql RDBMS

Comment: Also I am trying to use apache drill to do exactly the same thing as you

Comment: Is Hive a real time query language? I thought its a map reducer which will take good few seconds to execute queries.

Comment: No it isn't but you can export the output to RDBMS for faster querying

Comment: Since you have cloudera version why aren't you using impala? I cant do that since i am using the apache version

Comment: I couldn't integrate imphal to hbase table... tried copying imphal's class path to hbase lib... same with hive.. I am not a Java  developer, it throws lot of java exceptions which are alien to me .. :(

Comment: well you could have asked that question and I am also not a java developer

Comment: Its a long story mate.. I have asked that question, but didn't received an answer.. Gave up on imphal and hive.. Now trying out phoenix. Never thought it would be this difficult to use a DB.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60824/discussion-between-antariksha-yelkawar-and-karthik).